# Faster way to find matches and append to a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have code that works. But it is slow and I'm hoping to speed it up so I can scale up to a data set of a couple-00,000 observations.

I have two data frames, one of which I convert to a data.table using the data.table package for fast lookups and joins. I want to record records from one data set when 3 fields match a record in a second data set.

Original.df (data frame) and LookHereForMatches.dt (data.table with key on a1, a2, a3). Original.df will have a 100,000 to 300,000 observations and LookHereForMatches.dt will probably be 2x.

I loop through each observation in Original.df and look for observations in LookHereForMatches.dt that match on certain criteria. I want several fields from LookHereForMatches.dt and several fields from Original.df. I use subset() to get just the columns I want.

Maybe someone can tell me which part of my code is the worst/slowest. I have to believe it's the rbind(cbind()) part. Doesn't seem like that's the right way to do it.

```
matched_data.df <- data.frame()
for( i in 1:nrow(Original.df)){
  a1 <- Original.df$col1
  a2 <- Original.df$col2
  a3 <- Original.df$col3
  # Use data.table library "join" functionality to get matches (will find at least 1 and up to 4 matches, usually only 1 or 2)
  match.df <- data.frame(LookHereForMatches.dt[J(a1, a2, a3)], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  # combine matches with original data and add to data.frame to create big list of data with matches
  matched_data.df <- rbind(cbind(match.df, Original.df[i,], stringsAsFactors=FALSE), matched_data.df)
}
```

UPDATE

Here is roughly what the data looks like. (Clearly a newbie at R and StackExchange. <strike>I'll figure out how to make the tables prettier and come back to fix that too.</strike> Thanks @joran for fixing my tables.) The tables are pretty basic stuff. I just want to find each row from the first table and match it to all appropriate rows in the second table on a1, a2, and a3. In the example, the first row from Original.df should be paired up with rows 1, 2, and 3 from the LookHereForMatches.dt table returning 3 rows.

```
Original.df <- read.table(textConnection('
a1  a2  a3  text.field  numeric.field
123 abc 2011-12-01  "some text"    1.0 
124 abc 2011-11-12  "some other text"  0.1 
125 bcd 2011-12-01  "more text"   1.2
'), header=TRUE)

LookHereForMatches.df <- read.table(textConnection('
a1  a2  a3  text.field  numeric.field   Status_Ind   
123 abc 2011-12-01  "some text"    10.5   0
123 abc 2011-12-01  "different text"   0.1    1
123 abc 2011-12-01  "more text"    0.1    1
125 bcd 2011-12-01  "other text"   4.3    0
125 bcd 2011-12-01  "text"     2.2    0
'), header=TRUE)

LookHereForMatches.dt <- data.table(LookHereForMatches.df, key=c("a1","a2","a3"))
```

Comment: Since I don't know what your data looks like, forgive me if this doesn't help... If you can provide a small sample of your data, you will get much better answers.  But can't you use something like a conditional to match?  `Origional.df[Origional.df$a1 %in% LookHereForMatchers.dt$a1 & Origional.df$a2 %in% LookHereForMatches.dt$a2,]`.  The `for loop` is slow, but the `rbind(cbind(...))` is much slower.  Ideally you could allocate the full size of `matched_data.df` before assigning.  If you cannot, using something like I wrote above should help some...

Comment: I don't understand (maybe because you haven't provided a reproducible example?) why you can't simply do one join between data.table's.

Comment: Updated to add some sample data. I'll look into %in%. As for the reason I can't do a join between data.tables... I'm new to R. I'll look into join as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `merge` will do what you're looking for; see `?merge` for details.

```
> merge(Original.df, LookHereForMatches.df, by=c("a1","a2","a3"))
   a1  a2         a3 text.field.x numeric.field.x   text.field.y
1 123 abc 2011-12-01    some text             1.0      some text
2 123 abc 2011-12-01    some text             1.0 different text
3 123 abc 2011-12-01    some text             1.0      more text
4 125 bcd 2011-12-01    more text             1.2     other text
5 125 bcd 2011-12-01    more text             1.2           text
  numeric.field.y Status_Ind
1            10.5          0
2             0.1          1
3             0.1          1
4             4.3          0
5             2.2          0
```

If you want more control, it's using `match` behind the scenes, something like this:

```
a <- with(Original.df, paste(a1, a2, a3, sep="\b"))
b <- with(LookHereForMatches.df, paste(a1, a2, a3, sep="\b"))
m <- match(b, a)
cbind(Original.df[m,], LookHereForMatches.df)
```

Also look up the `all` options to control what it does when things don't appear in both data sets.

```
merge(Original.df, LookHereForMatches.df, by=c("a1","a2","a3"), all=TRUE)
```

As for speed with large data sets, you can get some speedup by using `data.table` but with 1e5 and 3e5 rows in each (as follows), on my system, the merge only takes 2.6 seconds and the match and cbind only 1.5 seconds.

```
set.seed(5)
N <- 1e5
Original.df <- data.frame(a1=1:N, a2=1, a3=1, text1=paste("hi",1:N))
LookHereForMatches.df <- data.frame(a1=sample(1:N, 3*N, replace=TRUE), 
                                    a2=1, a3=1, text2=paste("hi", 1:(3*N)))
```

Comment: Thank you. That's it. suffix=c("_first","_second") or something close to that also helps with the naming. Still giving %in% a try. But this appears to do the trick. I'll post some timing details when I test it and get it all working properly.

Comment: I'm still not totally clear how the cbind matches up the rows correctly, but since merge() gets me where I need to go, I'll stick with that.

Timing:
    1,000 rows in original.df; 3,000 rows in LookHereForMatches.df
    merge(): 0.015; for loop: 3.1
    10,000 rows; 30,000 rows
    merge(): 0.25; for loop 74 seconds.